# Is there something similar to the "find" command in Python?

Tags: python, iterator

On Linux there's a command called "find" where you can search for specific filenames. Is there any way I can search for a specific method when using dir()?

For example, when I do:

```
a = ["hey", "bro", "you're", "awesome"]
dir(a)
```

The result is:

```
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'clear', 'copy', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
```

Can I do a **dir(a) | find iter** to get the result ____iter____? 
Is there any quick way to do a search in this way in Python?

Comment: Perhaps: `[x for x in dir(a) if x == '__iter__']`? Or `filter(lambda x: x == '__iter__', dir(a))`

Comment: `if "__iter__" in dir(a):`? Or just try to get it directly (i.e. `a.__iter__`) and capture the `AttributeError` if it doesn't exist? Or `getattr(a, "__iter__", None)` (replace `None` with whatever default you might want). Or...

Comment: Err, the Python equivalent to `find` would be a thing that looks for files, such as `os.walk()`. If you're looking not for files but for method names, that's something *very* different.

Comment: The "find" command in POSIX systems does a recursive descent list of all paths.  Please change your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dir(a)` returns a list of names in `a`, so you can use a list comprehension to print out only the ones you care about:

```
print([s for s in dir(a) if 'iter' in s])
```

You can make this a function if you want to search easily:

```
def find_dir(search_string, a):
    return [s for s in dir(a) if search-string in s]
find_dir('iter', a)
```

Comment: That works. I was just wondering whether there was a quicker way without list comprehensions. It gets tedious when I'm using the interpreter to make that list comprehension every time. Looks like i'll just make my own custom import.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) function in the python pathlib. It select files based on a pattern.